# Does Google Colab have an XML preview function similar to magic table for dataframes?

Tags: xml, google-colaboratory

I wonder if Google Colab has a feature for seeing a human-friendly preview of XML similar to the visualisation of dataframes in magic tables when you use the `display(df)` function.

My colleagues and I want to read XML "on the fly" to check if our scripts have correctly transferred the information to a relational DB.